# How to know if React lazy load component is working or not? React js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, lazy-loading

[image]I am using **react lazy load component** npm library, How can I know whether its working or not? I have used onContentVisible which is available in **react lazy load component** library docs. Even Without scrolling, In developer tools, Network tab says 84 requests are sent which is the maximum requests for my web page. How can I figure it out?

Comment: Are you using any node module to achieve React Lazy load component or React.lazy?

Comment: Yes I am using - React lazy load component

Comment: In order to figure out if the lazy component, you need to invoke that component.

Comment: Invoke?How? I have read docs and used as per docs. onContentVisible is working. Couldn't exactly know whether is working or not?

Comment: It seems that you are not using official React.lazy https://reactjs.org/docs/code-splitting.html#reactlazy. I think that you are using `react-lazy-load` npm module because it supports `onContentVisible`. Kindly add more information about what you are using and add [mcve]

Comment: Thank you for providing resources, I changed my code and implemented according to official React.lazy. But what I want is whenever I try to scroll, Components should load accordingly.. I have added code

Comment: and yes I had used react lazy load component before.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Chrome dev tools, press command-shift-p (Mac) or control-shift-p (Windows) to open the command menu. Select Show Coverage and click the Reload button and reload your home page, and Chrome will show you what has loaded.