# Next/React lazy load not working as expected for components

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-suspense, react-lazy-load

Hi all I am new in Next/react I am trying to lazy load one component. What my expectation is that component must loads when it is visible in user view port or once a page is fully rendered.
Its html code should not come in the first response. But after debugging I found that it is not working as expected.

I have tried below approaches

index.js

```
const ProductTabbedWidget = React.lazy(() => import('../../../components/ProductSearch/ProductTabbed/ProductTabbedWidget'));
```

and

```
const ProductTabbedWidget = dynamic(() => import('../../../components/ProductSearch/ProductTabbed/ProductTabbedWidget'),{suspense:true,});

<Suspense fallback={<div>Loading</div>}>
<ProductTabWidget vehicleType={type}></ProductTabWidget>
</Suspense>
```

Component: ProductTabbedWidget

```
const ProductTabWidget = (props) => {

const getData = () =>{
// fetch the data from api 
// ex. locahost:7000/api/get-data
}
useEffect(()=>{
  getData()
},[])
return (
    <div></div>
)
```

}

The call to this api is visible in chrome when the page loads.
I am confused if react lazy is the rigt way to do this. I know this can be done using javascript but is there any way to do it ony by react or next.
I have gone through these answers but none of them works.

[React suspense/lazy delay?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54158994/react-suspense-lazy-delay)

[How to know if React lazy load component is working or not? React js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53412424/how-to-know-if-react-lazy-load-component-is-working-or-not-react-js)
react
[React lazy loading - when to use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60390144/react-lazy-loading-when-to-use)

Answer (score 0):

In react side use lazy loading like this.

```
import React, { Suspense } from 'react';

const OtherComponent = React.lazy(() => import('./OtherComponent'));

function MyComponent() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Suspense fallback={<div>Loading...</div>}>
        <OtherComponent />
      </Suspense>
    </div>
  );
}
```

In Next JS

```
import dynamic from 'next/dynamic'

const DynamicComponent = dynamic(() =>
  import('../components/hello').then((mod) => mod.Hello)
)

function Home() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Header />
      <DynamicComponent />
      <p>HOME PAGE is here!</p>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Home
```